# Is there a way to bulk create tile assets from a collection of tile images?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to bulk create tile assets of this type https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tilemap-TileAsset.html

From a collection of of 2D sprites before runtime? I suspect there might be a way to do it using an editor script like this:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.CreateAsset.html

It would be a huge time saver rather than having to individually duplicate tiles in the project folder and selecting default images for new tiles one by one.

In this case I'd rather avoid the usual drag + drop into tile palettes because the tiles generated by that process can't really be accessed individually via code unless I instantiate a tilemap prefab, which I don't want to do.

Comment: You mean like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zNv_3knZf1A)?

Comment: @derHugo, nope, that's a tilemap that uses a tile palette, which I specifically said I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the answer I was looking for.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class TileParser : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const string inputPath = "Tilesets";
    private const string outputPath = "Assets/Tiles/";
    [MenuItem("Pre Production/Parse Tiles")]
    public static void ParseTiles()
    {
        var sprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>(inputPath);

        foreach(var sprite in sprites)
        {
            Tile t = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Tile>();
            t.name = sprite.name;
            t.sprite = sprite;
            AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(t, string.Format("{0}{1}.asset", outputPath, t.name));
        }
        Debug.Log(sprites.Length + " tiles created at " + outputPath);
    }
}
```